# Get the char* value with python gdb

Tags: python, debugging, gdb, gdb-python

With GDB and Python I tried to get the char* value on `x1` register

```
python
a= gdb.execute("x/s $x1", to_string=True)
print(a)
end
```

But I got
`0xbb4aaa:       "SomeString"`

I want to get only the `SomeString` without the address

How can I do that directly with python GDB (without regex/split)

Comment: Try `gdb.convenience_variable('x1').string()`.

Comment: @ssbssa `$x1` is a register ,not a variable .  that doesn't work

Comment: In that case, `gdb.selected_frame().read_register('x1').cast(gdb.lookup_type('char').pointer()).string()`.

Comment: @ssbssa Wow that crazy command, work, so strange that there is no simple python command for that

Comment: Not sure what you mean, that's a very specific thing you needed here, why should a 'simple' command exist for exactly that? You can just create your own function if you need this a lot.

Comment: @ssbssa you can write that as an answer so I will mark that

Comment: Another alternative that's not as efficient, but is compact: `a = gdb.execute('printf "%s", $x1', to_string=True)`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick write that as an answer please

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same problem and was super annoyed by the output of the address. Using the method `.string()` worked for me:

```py
print(a.string())
```